# WP Ajax DB issues

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, jquery

I am having a weird issue in regards to getting data from a DB Table via AJAX.

My outcome is to get the employees from the DB and into a dropdown list, but i haven't been able to get it to work.
So here is my code and what i have done so far and the current results.

1. I have registered the action and function in WP:

   ```
   add_action('wp_ajax_get_users_dropdown', array( $this, 'get_users_dropdown'));
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_users_dropdown', array( $this, 'get_users_dropdown'));
   ```
2. I created the PHP code to retrieve the employees from custom DB Table:

   ```
   public function get_users_dropdown()
   {
    $mydb = new wpdb('*****','*****','******','*****'); //External DB Auth
    $data = $mydb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM employee WHERE email IS NOT NULL");

    echo wp_json_encode($data);
    die();
   }
   ```
3. Then, I created my JS function to call the PHP code which gets called in the $(document).ready():

   ```
   function populate_users_dropdown()
   {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : MyAjax.ajaxurl, // Including ajax file
        data: { 
            action: 'get_users_dropdown',
            security: MyAjax.security
        },
        success: function(response) { // Show returned data using the function.
            //console.log("> response: ", response );
            // send data to function
            display_users_dropdown(response);
        },
        error: function() {
           // console.log("FAILED...");
        }
    });
   }
   ```
4. From there I pass the successful response from the AJAX call to a function to handle the outputted data.

   ```
   function display_users_dropdown(responseData)
   {
    console.log ( "++ display_users_dropdown - ", responseData.length, responseData[0].id, responseData[0].name, responseData );
    }
   ```

The output from the console is:

```
   ++ display_users_dropdown: 1309 undefined undefined 
        [{"id":"4","name":"John Game"},
            {"id":"5","name":"Cyan Bergan"},
            {"id":"7","name":"Stephen Rogers"},
       ...]
```

But what i am getting in the console.log is not right, if i log the "responseData" only I get 36 items in the array, but if i use the above, id and name are undefined, length is 1309 instead of 36 *(DB table only has 47 entries)* and the array shows up fine.

I am not sure why this i doing this and would like a second option.

Comment: Why are you doing that `$mydb = new wpdb` - you could've just replace that with `global $wpdb;` and use `$wpdb->get_results()`? And if you want just (at most) 36 results, then use something like `LIMIT 36` in your SQL query. Also, have you considered using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) - it's not required, but it seems to me as a better choice since you're outputting a JSON data.

Comment: This is an internal website. And the DB is not a Core WP table it's getting the data from a seperate DB. And this method works fine for all other instances appart from this one. There are 47 employees in the DB with 36 have emails.

Comment: Ok then, but if your table is in another database, but uses the *same user and password* as the ones for your WordPress database, you could use the [`select()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/select/) for selecting your custom database using the current database connection.

Comment: And actually (as you've figured it out), the `responseData` in your code is a string (it's the response text/body returned by the server) and not an array. If you want it be automatically converted to an array, use [`wp_send_json()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) or add `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()` args, although yes, `JSON.parse()` also works for manually converting the data to an array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  data = **JSON.parse**(data); was needed on the JS side for receiving the data.